# Ridiculous amount of warnings in xcode 6 beta 7

Tags: xcode, swift, warnings, beta

In Xcode 6 beta 7, my warnings are divided into two sections, for example if one is called "my app" the other would be called "my app project". I have fixed all warnings I have received in the "my app" section ( there were only 3-4). On the "my app project" section however, I have over 42,000 warnings! It has been this way since before I even wrote any code and created my empty project. I always assumed this was a beta issue but I would like to know if everyone else is experiencing the same thing. I am unable to even look at what the problems are as Xcode freezes when I try due to the overwhelming number of warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release notes provide some details into the errors, seems to be the evolution of Swift:

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_7_apzr94/xcode_6__beta_7_release_notes.pdf

From the release notes:

Swift Language

• A large number of Foundation, UIKit, CoreData, SceneKit, SpriteKit, Metal APIs have been audited for optional conformance, removing a significant number of implicitly unwrapped optionals from their interfaces. This clarifies the nullability of their properties, arguments and return values of their methods. This is an ongoing effort that started shipping in beta 5.

These changes replace T! with either T? or T depending on whether the value can be null or not null, respectively. If you find a case that was changed incorrectly, please file a radar and include the tag ‘#IUO’ in the subject line. Please do not file feature requests about APIs that are still marked as T!, we know about them.

If you encounter a method for which the return value is incorrectly considered non-nullable, or a property that is incorrectly considered non-nullable, you can work around the problem by immediately wrapping the result in an optional:

```
  var fooOpt: NSFoo? = object.reallyMightReturnNil()
  if let foo = fooOpt { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any issues like that in any of the releases including Xcode 6 Beta 7. Each beta release I usually end up with about 100 or so errors due to changes in syntax but they only take half an hour or so to go through and resolve.

Comment: Nope, no unexpected warnings. Again, get a few syntax warnings mainly to due will AnyObject or explicit non nullable (? vs !) but just go through and change the code to resolve.